# How to get authorizer email id in yahoo api?

Tags: c#, yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

I am working on yahoo api as given in the online doc - https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/. Here in the section 'Making API Requests' they are saying that with the Access Token make HTTP GET request to the url 'https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/abcdef123/profile?format=json'.
I have made the get request to it and the response i got it -

```
<profile cache="true" ns2:uri="https://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/BYY5K3R37KL4IWYRFSTYUJWDT4/profile" xmlns:ns2="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" xmlns="http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/profile/social.profile"><guid>BYY5K3R37KL4IWYRFSTYUJWDT4</guid><agecategory>A</agecategory><blended>NONE</blended><created>2008-11-18T07:06:25Z</created><familyname>Singh</familyname><givenname>Yogi</givenname><img><height>192</height><imageurl>https://s.yimg.com/wv/images/92b46b9b50d2026fb0301a4c56c159fc_192.png</imageurl><size>192x192</size><width>192</width><intl>in</intl><jurisdiction>in</jurisdiction><lang>en-IN</lang><location>new york</location><membersince>2008-09-08T06:27:47Z</membersince><migrationsource>1</migrationsource><nickname>Yogi</nickname><nux>3</nux><profilemode>PUBLIC</profilemode><profilestatus>ACTIVE</profilestatus><profileurl>http://profile.yahoo.com/BYY5K3R37KL4IWYRFSTYUJWDT4</profileurl><searchable>true</searchable><updated>2015-01-20T12:27:33Z</updated><isconnected>false</isconnected><profilehidden>false</profilehidden><profilepermission>PRIVATE</profilepermission></profile>
```

The problem is that the response does not contain the authrizer email id, so how to know who authorizes my yahoo app? 
Can somebody tell me how to get the email id of the person who authorizes my yahoo app?
thanks